# How to observe and track a single value from two renderUI elements in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

Here is a simple app where the user can either type (numericInput, bpm_numeric) or slide (sliderInput, bpm_slider) the input value. Both of these UI elements should stay in-sync with either choice. However, the output only needs to be tracked once.  Below I am tracking it twice, but I only need one copy of the "selection/input" from the user. I think I need to use `reactiveValues`, but I am not sure of the approach.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

    titlePanel("Reverb & Delay Calculator"),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            uiOutput("bpm_numeric"),
            uiOutput("bpm_slider")
        ),
        mainPanel(
            p("Numeric value is:"),
            verbatimTextOutput("numeric_val"),
            p("Slider value is:"),
            verbatimTextOutput("slider_val")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    output$bpm_numeric = renderUI({
        numericInput(
            "bpm_numeric",
            "BPM Numeric",
            value = 60, min = 40, max = 300
        )
    })

    output$bpm_slider = renderUI({
        sliderInput(
            "bpm_slider",
            "BPM Slider",
            value = 60, min = 40, max = 300
        )
    })

    # See how I can track "both", but really I only need to track "one" since
    # they should stay in-sync with one another. Maybe reactiveValues???
    output$numeric_val <- renderText({ input$bpm_numeric })
    output$slider_val <- renderText({ input$bpm_slider })

    observeEvent(input$bpm_numeric, {
        val = input$bpm_numeric
        updateSliderInput(session, "bpm_slider", value = val)
    })

    observeEvent(input$bpm_slider, {
        val = input$bpm_slider
        updateNumericInput(session, "bpm_numeric", value = val)
    })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: Shiny App]

*NOTE: While I am currently using `uiOuput()` + `renderUI()` + `update___Input()`, this is not necessarily a requirement. I am open to other approaches provided that the input UI's stay in sync I have one copy of the synced output.*

Comment: If you only need to respond to one of them why do you have two `renderText` blocks? The `observeEvent` blocks make sure that they stay in sync, from there anything that needs that value should be able to depend on only one of them.

Comment: why don't you just delete one of the `renderText` outputs?

Comment: @r2evans - I suppose I'm looking to generalize rather than just "pick" one of the two? I agree the choice is arbitrary, but I would like to think there's some method of abstracting this vs. locking in to one particular choice?

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing some of what you're saying, but to me the generic solution is precisely "depend on only one of them". In SQL, you have `coalesce` that gives you just the first non-null of its arguments; it seems like you want something akin to that here. I don't find any utility in that, frankly, since: (1) I know the id of all of them so can pick one, and (2) I control the up-to-date-ness of all candidates. In a more complicated example, trying to conditionally depend on more than one can easily result in repeat-dependencies, causing at best flickering, possibly unnecessary computation.

Comment: Are you trying to generalize "how to use that number", or how to make sure that "2 *or more* UI elements are kept in sync to the same value"?

Comment: @r2evans both with a preference on "how to use that number"

Answer (score 1):

Here's a thought. It is able to generalize *a little*, but it still relies on you knowing perfectly which ids you want to combine in this manner.

Mods to your current example:

1. Define a global `defbmp <- 60`, useful to make sure all elements are starting at the same place.
2. Outside of the new `useval` reactive, replace *all* references to `input$bpm_numeric` or `_slider` with `useval()`.
3. Useful for state-tracking, add `lastval` reactive value.
4. Finally, the `useval <- eventReactive({},{})` block, depending on each of the to-be-synced elements.

Final product (excluding the `ui` component, no changes there):

```r
defbpm <- 60                                       # new

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    output$bpm_numeric = renderUI({
        numericInput(
            "bpm_numeric",
            "BPM Numeric",
            value = defbpm, min = 40, max = 300    # update
        )
    })

    output$bpm_slider = renderUI({
        sliderInput(
            "bpm_slider",
            "BPM Slider",
            value = defbpm, min = 40, max = 300    # update
        )
    })

    output$numeric_val <- renderText({ useval() }) # update
    output$slider_val <- renderText({ useval() })  # update

    lastval <- shiny::reactiveVal(defbpm)          # new
    useval <- eventReactive({
      input$bpm_numeric
      input$bpm_slider
    }, {
      newval <- setdiff(c(input$bpm_numeric, input$bpm_slider), lastval())
      if (length(newval) > 0) {
        if (newval != input$bpm_numeric) updateNumericInput(session, "bpm_numeric", value = newval)
        if (newval != input$bpm_slider) updateSliderInput(session, "bpm_slider", value = newval)
        lastval(newval)
      }
      lastval()
    })                                             # new

}
```

Ways to improve this (I don't know at the moment):

1. programmatically define the elements to keep synced, such as a `character` vector of ids;
2. update `eventReactive` to have the conditional expression be generated programmatically, I'm just not a guru-enough to do this at the moment; and
3. determine at run-time if a given id represents a `numericInput` or a `sliderInput` (or something else), so that the `update*` functions can be called more generically.